# Create Group like WhatsApp, BBM in XMPP with (a)Smack

Tags: xmpp, multiuserchat, groupchat

Can I implement groupchat like WhatsApp or BBM in XMPP Asmack? I'm using Openfire Server.
I already implemented the basic multiuserchat in XMPP (http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html), but it's not contain all the features that i needed.

I need the full features of group chat like :

- groups can persist user no matter if they are online or not.
- deliver offline messages to a group member (when he comes online).

Should I customize the server? or there are any Standard about this group feature?
I really need help for this problem.

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Persistent XMPP MUC (XEP-45), like WhatsApp groupchats](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25982426/persistent-xmpp-muc-xep-45-like-whatsapp-groupchats)

Comment: @Richard, Have you found the solution? I am also looking the same functionality. Please reply. Thanks in advance...

Answer (score -1):

You should use a **packet listener** for group chat messages. Run this packet listener in a service so that group chats are update even when the app is not running in foreground. Then check the ***sender id*** from packet and update your data base accordingly. Check the code below.

```
PacketFilter filter = new MessageTypeFilter(Message.Type.groupchat);
            yourXmppConnection.addPacketListener(new PacketListener() {

                @Override
                public void processPacket(Packet packet) {
                    Message message = (Message) packet;
                    String received_message=message.getBody();
                    String from_user=message.getFrom();

                        // Add incoming message to the list view or similar
                    }
                }
            }, filter);
```

Comment: That does not achieve the requested functionality.