# Persistent Group using XMPP

Tags: mobile, xmpp, chat, strophe, multiuserchat

I am using **XMPP** and **MUC** for creating a group and it works fine till the user is online. The user leaves the group as soon as he goes offline. I want a user to stay in the room when he is offline and receive the unseen messages when he comes back. How to achieve this in XMPP. And how to create group and add users dynamically.

*Can i make the user online all the time..is it is a good approach.? if so then how can i do this - making user online all the time*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Persistent XMPP MUC (XEP-45), like WhatsApp groupchats](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25982426/persistent-xmpp-muc-xep-45-like-whatsapp-groupchats)

Answer (score 2):

XMPP MUC is based on user presence. A new upcoming protocol address this issue. It is called MIX: https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0369.html

It is still preliminary, but you can expect fast iterations and improvements.